# Error with pg-connection-string and sequelize in a React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to use the sequelize ORM with a React application. I've installed the sequelize and pg-connection-string packages, but I am getting an error when trying to connect to the database. The error message is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js 4:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages, clearing the npm cache, and using a different version of the packages, but I am still getting the same error.

I am using the following versions:

React: 16.13.1
Sequelize: 6.3.5
pg-connection-string: 2.0.0
Here is my code:

```
  const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('texteditor', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});

const Database = sequelize.define('database', {
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  content: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  }
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
sequelize.sync();
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So typically you do not connect to databases in the UI layer of an application. Likely the reason it can't retrieve the `fs` module is that you're running in a browser, where the sequelize package expects you to be using the node runtime. This is where you would build a backend server using Node.JS, which would connect to the DB and in turn respond to the UI with the information it needs.